# How do I assign a variable to be used outside of the loop?

Tags: python, scope

I'm really new to python or programming in general.

I am trying to make a function that draws input from the user and check if it is an integer.

However, after checking that the input is an integer, I am unable to use the variable outside of the loop, with an error message shown below:

```
python3.7 new.py 
How much is your balance in your account?
>123
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "new.py", line 14, in <module>
print(f"Thank you, your account balance is {b}.")
NameError: name 'b' is not defined



def inputintegertest():
    while True:
        try:
            a = int(input(">"))
            b = "${:.2f}".format(a)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a number.")

print("How much is your balance in your account?")

inputintegertest()

print(f"Thank you, your account balance is {b}.")
```

Comment: `return b` from inputintegertest. b is local to the function so it is not seen outside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the value of b from function to be used outside the function:

```
def inputintegertest():
    while True:
        try:
            a = int(input(">"))
            b = "${:.2f}".format(a)
            return b
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a number.")


print("How much is your balance in your account?")

b = inputintegertest()

print(f"Thank you, your account balance is {b}.")

print('Welcome ' )
```

Comment: `return` already `break`'s the `while`. No need for both

Comment: you **do** need the `while True` to re`try` a wrong input. You do not need the `break`

Comment: I think break is needed to break the while loop when input is correct

Comment: replace `break` with `return b`. `return` also will exit the `while`

Comment: Thank you for all your help! appreciate it alot